# Configuring spatialite database access for Python 2.6.6

Tags: python, sqlite, spatialite

I'm working on a GIS project, and I would like to implement and test some geo-spatial algorithms in Python. For this purpose, I will not only need sqlite, but also spatialite, in order to store and query the location data. Now I've tried to install the pyspatialite package, but no matter what Python version I tried (I tried all versions from 2.6 to 3.3), the pip keeps insisting, that none of the existing sqlite packages are compatible with my version of Python.

If I try to do this using easy_install, I get a traceback and an error:

```
AttributeError: MSVCCompiler instance has no attribute 'compiler'
```

And that also occurs, if I try to install the package manually, by executing the setup.py file.

From what I've already searched, some people suggest to connect to a spatialite database somehow using sqlite and loading extension, but frankly I have no idea how to do it, and couldn't understand any of these answers. I will be really grateful if someone here is able to propose a solution in a clear, step-by step way, as I'm not a very experienced Python programmer yet. Thanks in advance.